# How to specify a Vim flag in the vimrc?

Tags: vimrc, startup

I know that you can pass several flags to Vim at startup.

For example: the `-w` flags enables to records every keystrokes on the file output.

```
vi -w output
```

But I wonder if there is a way of doing this from the vimrc file, without having the `-w` flag at vim startup.

More generally: how can I specify a vim flag/option from within the vimrc ?

Comment: Record a macro in a register, with `q`. Then, paste the register content to a file. `:h -w` hints to the `complex-repeat` section, which actually describes the Vim macro system. In general, you read `:h starting.txt` and hope to find there and indication to the corresponding `vimrc` option :)

Comment: Hello, I saw this it could be a workaround but I don't find it satisfying... Meanwhile I updated my question to make it more generic

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. But you can create a shell alias, which has *roughly* the same effect.

Comment: I didn't wanted to do so ... but I might find that I have no other choice ... What do you think about creating a script that would reload vim with appropriated flags ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible from Vim. You can use `!` and `system()`, but both will leave the original process in place (it doesn't replace the original Vim process). You could do it with a wrapper shell script of course, but that doesn't seem easier than a shell alias.

Comment: Imagine a program that, when started with the `-s` flag, acts as a server, and, without it, will start as a client. It is not *necessary* that the program would always be written in such a way that the client could become a server, or viceversa, *while running*.

Comment: I perfectly understand your point, but I think, as the desired effect only affect Vim, I didn't want to use external configuration. The idea behind all this was to make a plugin that be self-sufficient.

Comment: I can understand why you'd want to enable that feature from your ~/.vimrc rather than from the command line, but in looking through the Vim source, the only way to enable that feature is with the `-w` flag.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? [(XY Problem)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/188334) For instance, if you are mainly interested on recording your keystrokes could try to use recording (`q`) with some autocommand to write it to a file from time to time.

Comment: I am trying to know how can I record all characters typed inside vim (like the `-w` flag does) but without having to alias vim.

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: I wanted this as well, because I'm using vim in tmux, and using tmus-resurrect to restore vim sessions, which doesn't work well currently with vim aliases. https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect/issues/440. Alas, I now resolved to just not use the aliases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

If the `-w` or `-W` flags are given, Vim will set the `scriptout` variable to a filehandle (`main.c`, `command_line_scan()`, around line 2374). This variable is referenced in only 2 other places; `getchar.c` for writing to the file, and `message.c`, to work around a problem which causes a character to be recorded twice.

The only viable options I see are either a shell alias, or a wrapper script which calls Vim with the `-w` flags.

Answer (score 0):

(This solution only works if you want to save your keystrokes to a single file)

You could alias it in your `bash_profile`, `bash_rc`, whichever one declares your path variables. This is one I did for `ls`:

```
alias ls="ls -pla"
```

So yours would be

```
alias vi="vi -w [output]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as discussed in the comments, the solution I wanted should not require an alias.